# how to make the input textbox to occupy entire div in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

how to make the  input textbox to occupy entire div in bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/yqV6q/167/

In the below code the textbox with label1 is not occupying entire div. how to make it and how to make it for other textbox also

```css
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 " style="background-color:yellow;color:red;padding:0;width:auto">Label1</div>
      <div class="col-md-8" style="padding:0;"><input type="text" style="width:100%" /> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 " style="background-color:yellow;color:red;padding:0;width:auto">Label2</div>
      <div class="col-md-8" style="padding:0;"><input type="text" style="width:100%" /> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 " style="background-color:yellow;color:red;padding:0;width:auto">Label3</div>
      <div class="col-md-8" style="padding:0;"><input type="text" style="width:100%" /> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify? Both the title div and the input box div take up 100% of their containing div. Are you asking about the body padding you have?